# Convergence of $a_n=(1-\frac12)^{(\frac12-\frac13)^{...^{(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1})}}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

let us moving to telescopic sum using exponent ,Assume we have this sequence: $a_n=(1-\frac12)^{(\frac12-\frac13)^{...^{(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1})}}}$ with $n\geq1$ , this sequence can be written as power of sequences  : ${x_n} ^ {{{y_n}^{c_n}}^\cdots} $ such that all them value are in $(0,1)$, I want to know if the titled sequence should converge to $1$ ? and how we can evaluate it for $n$ go to $\infty$  ?

Comment: I doubt it goes to $1$.  If it did, then presumably as similar argument would show that $$b_n=(\frac12-\frac13)^{(\frac13-\frac14)^{...^{(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1})}}}\to1,$$ but then $a_n\to (1-\frac12)^1=1/2$.

Comment: @zeraouliarafik Wowie, what a cool problem. May I ask how this came up? Was it just your own curiosity, or did a friend post it to you?

Comment: No, it is my own problem , The motivation is to look what about telescopic using power

Comment: it does seem to go to 1. Recursion is g(n) = g(n-1)^(1/(n*(n+1)) with g(1)=1/2. Python code: g = lambda n: g(n-1)**(1.0/(n*(n+1))) if n>1 else 0.5
print list(g(i) for i in range(1,13)). First 12 values: 0.5, 0.8908987181403393, 0.9904191474668262, 0.9995187636226662, 0.9999839550550974, 0.9999996179745105, 0.9999999931781149, 0.9999999999052516, 0.9999999999989473, 0.9999999999999905, 0.9999999999999999

Comment: @user625 Nope, your recursion is wrong. Your recursion would give the sequence
$$a_n=(1/2)^{(1/6)(1/12)(1/20)...(1/n(n+1))}$$

Comment: $a_1=1/2$, $a_{n+1}=a_n^{1/(n+1)(n+2)}$, then $0<a_n<1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. And clearly this means $a_n<a_n^{1/(n+1)(n+2)}=a_{n+1}$. Thus from monotone convergence theorem it converges?

Comment: @Frpzzd you are right.

Comment: tried to fix the python code.
for n in range(1,20):
    x=1
    for i in range(n,1,-1):
        x = (1.0/(i*(i+1)))**x
    print n,(0.5)**x

This produces:
1 0.5
2 0.89089871814
3 0.550456614108
4 0.867251251433
5 0.563420476229
6 0.860842989782
7 0.566834725218
8 0.859253542289
9 0.567613178306
10 0.858923317165
11 0.567759886133
12 0.858866824773

Comment: If I didn't screw it up again, it looks like odd and even n converge to two separate values. Would be interesting to derive those two values.

Comment: @user625, look the below answer

Comment: @zeraouliarafik the answer just confirms what I already said in the comment above. You can calculate the value of sequence for a finite n using the code I posted. Since the sequence needs to be computed backward, deriving closed form expressions will probably be difficult.

Comment: The expression does converge to 1.

Comment: Here's a python script to do that: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ev9fLOttdWoXSt9ZneDYT8f4tn643u3i3LHeH5GXn2c/edit?usp=drivesdk

Comment: From the comments one can now guess that this is supposed to be unwrapped starting at the right end. It might be a good idea to say this clearly in the question itself.

Comment: comment above is rightly important: are you defining $a^{\,b^{\,c} }  = \left( {a^{\,b} } \right)^c $, or $a^{\,b^{\,c} }  = a^{\,\left( {b^{\,c} } \right)} $ ? you shall clarify this in your post (see [this wikipedia article on iterated powers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration)

Comment: Note that you can write this as
$$
f(x)=\left(\frac{1}{\left(x+1\right)\left(x+2\right)}\right)^{{\left(\frac{1}{\left(x+2\right)\left(x+3\right)}\right)}^{f(x+2)}}
$$
and you are looking for $f(0)$. By coincidence $f(0) \approx f(2)$ and you get an approximate solution by solving the above equation replacing $f(2)$ by $f(0)$.

Comment: $f(0) \approx f(2)$ for even towers.

Comment: I don't think the limit exists. There should always be a gap between the odd subsequence $\{a_{2n+1}\}$ and $\{a_{2n}\}$, but I can't prove it is still true after taking $n \to \infty$.

Comment: I know this is now an old post, but you should give a look at this post too: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3640774/does-frac12-frac34-frac56-ldots-converge/3642194#3642194

Comment: I posted over there a proof of convergence based on the monotonic behaviour of the subsequences of even and odd terms, but I didn't figure out anything else about that problem specifically.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Numeric calculation of the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n \ge 1}$ suggests that the terms are bounded, but alternate between approximately $$0.56778606544394002098000796382530333102219963214866$$ and $$0.85885772008416606762434379473241623070938618180813,$$ but I do not have a proof.  This convergence is extremely rapid, and the alternating nature suggests that it is important to look at even and odd $n$ separately.

Comment: Would you mind also posting two plots of $a_n$, one for odd and one for even $n$?

Comment: This dichotomy is clear from just looking at the sequence since the first power (using up the last two exponents) is $\epsilon^{\epsilon'}\simeq 1$, then the next one is $\simeq\epsilon''^1$ and so on in an alternating pattern, until one arrives at roughly $(1/2)^1$ or $(1/2)^{1/6}$.

Comment: Also it is clear (by induction) that the "odds" go up and the "evens" go down, so the only problem (unless you insist on exact values of the limits, which is most likely out of question) is to show that they stay separated.

Comment: That sequence is already assigned A328941 and A328942

Comment: @Szeto: not a plot but a list of convergence up to $n$ and $n+1$ steps $$\small \begin{bmatrix} 
 1 & 0.50000000 & 0.89089872 \\ 
 3 & 0.55045661 & 0.86725125 \\ 
 5 & 0.56342048 & 0.86084299 \\ 
 7 & 0.56683473 & 0.85925354 \\ 
 9 & 0.56761318 & 0.85892332 \\ 
 11 & 0.56775989 & 0.85886682 \\ 
 13 & 0.56778272 & 0.85885879 \\ 
 15 & 0.56778570 & 0.85885783 \\ 
 17 & 0.56778603 & 0.85885773 \\ 
 19 & 0.56778606 & 0.85885772 \\ 
 21 & 0.56778607 & 0.85885772 \\ 
 23 & 0.56778607 & 0.85885772
 \end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 6):

This only shows that the limit cannot be $1$.

Note that $a_n=(1/2)^{(1/6)^{(1/12)^\cdots}}$, where the "$\cdots$" are meant to terminate at the exponent $1/(n(n+1))$.

As a general rule, if $0\lt r\lt1$ and $0\lt a\lt b\lt1$, then $0\lt r\lt r^b\lt r^a\lt1$.  It follows that

$$0\lt(1/12)\lt(1/12)^{(1/20)^\cdots}\lt1$$

and thus also that

$$0\lt(1/6)\lt(1/6)^{(1/12)^{(1/20)^\cdots}}\lt(1/6)^{(1/12)}\lt1$$

so that, finally,

$$0.5504566141\approx(1/2)^{(1/6)^{(1/12)}}\lt(1/2)^{(1/6)^{(1/12)^\cdots}}\lt(1/2)^{(1/6)}\approx0.89089871814$$

These bounds accord with what heropup found.

Comment: Did you miss $3\cdot 4 =12$ ?

Comment: @Diger, yes, you're right. I'll fix it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

$\mathbf{Updated\ 22.06.18}$

[Some first values](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B2.%5E(-1),%202.%5E(-6%5E(-1)),%202.%5E(-6%5E(-12%5E(-1))),%202.%5E(-6%5E(-12%5E(-20%5E(-1)))),%202.%5E(-6%5E(-12%5E(-20%5E(-30%5E(-1))))),%202.%5E(-6%5E(-12%5E(-20%5E(-30%5E(-42%5E(-1)))))),%202.%5E(-6%5E(-12%5E(-20%5E(-30%5E(-42%5E(-56%5E(-1)))))))%7D) of the sequence 
$$a_n=\{2^{-1}, 2^{-6^{-1}}, 2^{-6^{-12^{-1}}},\dots 2^{-6^{-12\dots^{{-(n(n+1))^{-1}}}}} \}$$
are
$$0.5, 0.890899, 0.550457, 0.867251, 0.56342, 0.860843, 0.566835\dots$$
Easy to see that the even and the odd sequences are different. On the other hand, if the limit 
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n$$ 
exists, it must be the limit of the each of the sequences.

Let 
$$t_n = (n(n+1))^{-((n+1)(n+2))^{-((n+2)(n+3))^{\dots}}},\tag1$$
then
$$t_{n} = (n(n+1))^{-t_{n+1}},\tag2$$
$$t_{n+1} = -\dfrac{\log t_{n}}{\log{(n(n+1))}}.\tag3$$

And now let us consider the sequence $T_n,$ such as

$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} T_n = \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} T_{n+1},\tag4$$
where $T_n$ is [the root of the equation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=T%3D-log(T)%2Flog(n%5E2%2Bn))
$$T_n = -\dfrac{\log T_n}{\log{(n(n+1))}},\tag5$$
$$T_n = e^{-W(\log(n^2+n))},\tag6$$
where $W(x)$ is the [Lambert W-function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html).

Easy to see that 
$$2^{-6^{\dots{-((n-1)n)^{-T_n}}}} = 2^{-6^{\dots{-((n-1)n)^{-(n(n+1))^{-T_n}}}}}.\tag7$$ 
This means that can be defined the sequence 
$$b_n = 2^{-6^{\dots{-((n-1)n)^{-t_n}}}},\tag8$$
where
$$b_1\approx2^{-e^{-W(\log(6))}},$$
$$b_2\approx2^{-6^{-e^{-W(\log(12))}}},$$
$$b_3\approx2^{-6^{-12^{-e^{-W(\log20))}}}}\dots,$$
with more weak difference between the odd/even subsequences.

This approach allows to get more stable estimation of $a$ and supplies the version $a\not=1.$

---

**Numerical calculation for the sequences**

Each value of the possible limit $a$ generates a sequence $t_n$ by formulas $(3)$. If the obtained sequence is't monotonic then the value of $a$ is wrong. 
Consideration of the case $n\to\infty$ allows to get the limits $a_l$ anh $a_h$ for the value of $a.$

For example, the value $a_h=0.719$ [generates the sequence](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B0.719,-+log_2+0.719,p,-log_12+p,-log_20(-log_12+p),q,-log_42+q,-log_56(-log_42+q),-log_72(-log_56(-log_42+q))%7D,where++p%3D-log_6(-+log_2+0.719),+q%3D-log_30(-+log_20(-log_12+p)))
$$t_n=\{0.719, 0.475936, 0.414381, 0.354528, 0.311916, 0.311697, 0.289595, 0.289775, 0.275267\},$$
which is not monotonic. Easy to see that sequences with $a>a_h$ are not monotonic too.

This allows to claim that $a<a_h < 0.719.$

Similarly, [one can show](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B0.711,-%20log_2%200.711,p,-log_12%20p,-log_20(-log_12%20p),q,-log_42%20q,-log_56(-log_42%20q),-log_72(-log_56(-log_42%20q))%7D,where%20%20p%3D-log_6(-%20log_2%200.711),%20q%3D-log_30(-%20log_20(-log_12%20p))) that $a> a_l > 0.711,$ considering the sequence
$$t_n=\{0.711, 0.492079, 0.395766, 0.373025, 0.329171, 0.326702, 0.299306, 0.299673, 0.281777\}$$

Therefore, the possible limit is bounded:
$$\boxed{a\in(0.711, 0.719)}.$$

At the same time, numerical calculation for $n=1\dots25$ ([step1](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B0.7144,-%20log_2%200.7144,p,-log_12%20p,-log_20(-log_12%20p),q,-log_42%20q,-log_56(-log_42%20q),-log_72(-log_56(-log_42%20q))%7D,where%20%20p%3D-log_6(-%20log_2%200.7144),%20q%3D-log_30(-%20log_20(-log_12%20p))), [step2](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B-log_90%200.28516,%20p,-log_132%20p,-log_156(-log_132%20p),q,-log_210%20q,-log_240(-log_210%20q),-log_272(-log_240(-log_210%20q))%7D,where%20%20p%3D-log_110(-log_90%200.28516),%20q%3D-log_182(-log_156(-log_132%20p))), [step3](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B-log_306%200.247059,%20p,-log_380%20p,-log_420(-log_380%20p),q,-log_504%20q,-log_552(-log_504%20q),-log_600(-log_552(-log_504%20q))%7D,where%20%20p%3D-log_342(-log_306%200.247059),%20q%3D-log_462(-log_420(-log_380%20p)))) shows that the sequence 
$$t_n \approx \{0.7144, 0.485196, 0.403627, 0.36511, 0.336331, 0.320376, 0.304538, 0.295368, 0.28516, 0.278835, 0.271703, 0.266864, 0.261595, 0.257678, 0.253603, 0.250333, 0.247059, 0.244275, 0.241561, 0.239157, 0.23685, 0.234751, 0.232899, 0.230797, 0.229206\dots\}$$ 
is monotonic for $n<25.$

On the other hand, if the infinity sequence $t_n,\ n\in 1,2\dots$ for some value $t_1$ is monotonic, then the issue limit exists and $a=t_1.$

Numeric calculation shows that a possible value of the issue limit is $a\approx 0.7144$, if it exists.

Comment: Note that $\frac{0.5677860+0.8588577}{2} \approx 0.71332$.

Comment: This argument *assumes* that the limit exists, i.e., that $t_n$ make sense. However this assumption seems rather unwarranted

Comment: @fedja Thanks, fixed.

Comment: @Diger If the limit exists at all.

Comment: I know. I just wanted to point out that even though the limit does not exist assuming it exists leads to the mean value of both "limits".

Comment: The meaning of the LambertW solution $T_n$ is probably that this precise value defines the boundary (only exact for $n \rightarrow \infty$) at which the value jumps between to two solutions. E.g.: Take $n=1000$ i.e. the even tower
$$
2^{-6^{\dots{-((n-1)n)^{-(n(n+1))}}}}
$$
with value $0.858857...$. Now consider
$$
2^{-6^{\dots{-((n-1)n)^{-(n(n+1))^{-T_n}}}}}
$$
and $T_{1000} \approx 0.141513$. If you decrease $T_n$ by some $\epsilon$ then you jump into the second solution $0.567786...$.

Comment: @Diger Thanks. I've added the numerical calculations, which gives the possible infinite limit $a\approx0,71441.$

Comment: @fedja The numerical calculation is added. Waiting for comments.

Comment: What are the biggest $n$ values you tried?

Comment: I'm also not sure how you get your
$$
t_n \approx \{0.714410, 0.485171, 0.403653, 0.365082, 0.336354, 0.320353
0.304555, 0.295353, 0.285170, 0.278825, 0.271708, 0.266859, 0.261597, 0.257675,
0.253604, 0.250330, 0.247059, 0.244273, 0.241560, 0.239155\}
$$
??

Comment: Each value of limit $a$ in an obvious way generates a consequence $t_n$. The value of $a$ can be considered if the sequence $t_n$ is monotonic. The criterion of the most probable consequence assumed the minimum of the mean square deviation from the consequence $T_n$.

Comment: @Diger I've tried $n=20$ and $n=30$. The difference of $a$ is $0.00001.$

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: @Diger See the updated text. Thank you for the discussion.

Comment: Dito. And btw: Stop calling it "consequences" ^^
That awakens completely wrong associations in me..

Comment: @Diger Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

It is perhaps interesting to note that the behaviour noted by previous posts is true for a wide class of functions defined by towers.

For all positive integers $i$ let $u_i$ be **any** real numbers such that $1>u_i>0$. Define $$a(n)=u_1^{u_{2}^{...^{u_n}}},b(n)=u_2^{u_{3}^{...^{u_n}}}.$$

**Lemma 1** $$a(1)<a(3)<a(5)<a(7)...$$ $$1>a(2)>a(4)>a(6)>a(8)...$$
**Proof**  $$a(N+2)-a(N)=u_1^{b(N+2)}-u_1^{b(N)}.$$
Therefore $a(N+2)-a(N)$ and $b{(N+2)}-b(N)$ have opposite signs.

Now $b(N+2)-b(N)$ is just $a(N+1)-a(N-1)$ for a different sequence and so all the inequalities of the lemma follow inductively from the trivial inequality $1>a(2)$.

**Lemma 2**

The terms $a(N)$ increase and decrease alternately.

**Proof**  $$a(N+2)-a(N+1)=u_1^{b(N+2)}-u_1^{b(N+1)}.$$ The proof now proceeds similarly to that of Lemma 1.

**Theorem**

The $a(2N)$ terms are m.d. to a limit $L$ and the $a(2N+1)$ terms are m.i. to a limit $l$, where $L\ge l$.

**Proof**

This is an immediate consequence of Lemmas 1 and 2 and the fact that the terms $a(N)$ are bounded by $0$ and $1$.

Answer (score 2):

*Too long for a comment*

The general idea is to interpolate the terms to get a function and then analyze its properties.

---

Let $\{a_n(x)\}$ be a sequence of once-differentiable functions.

Define the recurrence relation $$A_n(x)=a_n(x)^{A_{n+1}(x)}$$ (where often the '$(x)$' part will be omitted for simplicity.)

Then, we have $$A_n'=A_n\left(A'_{n+1}\ln a_n+A_{n+1}\frac{a_n'}{a_n}\right)$$

---

Let $$t_n=\frac1n-\frac1{n+1}$$
Let $$H(x)=
\begin{cases}
1, &x<0 \\
\frac{\cos(\pi x)+1}2, &0\le x\le1\\
0, &x>0
\end{cases}
$$
Define $$a_n(x)=(t_n)^{H(n-x)}$$

OP’s sequence  thus becomes
$$\{A_1(1),A_1(2),A_1(3),\cdots\}$$

Then, the limit of the OP's sequence (i.e. $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n}$, not to be confused with the $a_n(x)$ in this answer) is $$A_1(\infty)\equiv \lim_{x\to\infty}A_1(x)$$

So our question would become

> Does $\lim_{x\to\infty}A_1(x)$ exists?

Let's analyze the derivatives.

Firstly, $$a_n'=-\ln(t_n)H'(n-x)a_n$$
So, $$A_n'=\overbrace{\cdots}^{\text{messy algebra}}=A_nb_n(A_{n+1}H'(n-x)-A'_{n+1}H(n-x))$$ where $b_n=\ln(n(n+1))$.

For $n<\lfloor x\rfloor$, $H'(n-x)=0$. Therefore, we can recursively write out
$$A_1'=\left(\prod^{\lfloor x\rfloor}_{k=1}(-A_kb_k)\right) A'_{\lfloor x\rfloor+1}$$

With $$A'_{\lfloor x\rfloor+1}=A_{\lfloor x\rfloor+1}b_{\lfloor x\rfloor+1}(A_{\lfloor x\rfloor+2}H'(\lfloor x\rfloor+1-x)-\underbrace{A'_{\lfloor x\rfloor+2}H(\lfloor x\rfloor+1-x)}_{=0})$$
we can finally write out something neater
$$A_1'=-\left(A_{\lfloor x\rfloor+2}\prod^{\lfloor x\rfloor+1}_{k=1}(-A_kb_k)\right)\frac{\sin\pi(x-\lfloor x\rfloor)}2$$

We can easily see the alternation of sign in $A_1’$: whenever $x$ increases one, $A_1’(x)$ changes sign. If the product does not converge to zero, then $A_1’(\infty)\ne0$; and, due to the keep changing of sign, one can expect $A_1(x)$ to keep going up and down as $x$ gets larger and larger. Thus one can argue that the limit $A_1(\infty)$ does not exist.

However, I cannot prove the product does not converge to zero.

Comment: In my opinion to find it's exact limit w'd be an open question

Comment: @zeraouliarafik I never attempted to find the exact limit:)

Comment: I shoud upvote to this answer

Comment: @zeraouliarafik By the way, what is your view on my answer?

Answer (score 1):

**To determine the upper limit (the lower limit can be found similarly)**

Let $a_n$ and $u_n$ be as defined in my earlier answer and define $F_n(x)$ to be $${u_{2n-1}^{{u_{2n}}^x}}$$
The following technical result will greatly simplify the working later.

**Lemma 3**

If $x\ge0.8$ and $u_{2n}\le u_{2n-1}\le0.033$, then $F_n(x)\ge0.8.$

**Proof**

As in Lemma 1, $F_n(x)$ will be minimised (for fixed $u_{2n-1}$) when $x$ is minimised and $u_{2n}$ is maximised.The result therefore follows from the inequality $${t^{t^{0.8}}}\ge 0.8$$ for $t\le 0.033.$

**The Inverse function**

Since  $F_n(x)$ is m.i. on $[0,1]$, it has an inverse. This is given by
$$G_n(x)=\frac{\ln(\frac{\ln x}{\ln (u_{2n-1})})}{\ln(u_{2n})}.$$
Then $$a_{2n}=F_1(F_2(...(F_n(1))),1=G_n(...(G_2(G_1(a_{2n})))$$

**Theorem**

The limit $L$ for the @zeraoulia rafik sequence satisfies $$0.8588<L<0.8589.$$

**Proof**

Direct calculation of the $a_n$ shows that $L<0.8589.$ 
Suppose that  $L\le 0.8588.$

Another direct calculation shows that $G_7(...(G_2(G_1(0.8588)))<0.8$ and therefore $G_7(...(G_2(G_1(L)))<0.8$.

Lemma 3 applies to the $G_i$ for $i>7$ and so, as $n\to \infty, G_n(...(G_2(G_1(L)))$  does **not** tend to $1$, a contradiction.

The calculation given in the theorem can, of course, be carried out to whatever degree of precision is required but I have no reason to question the answer provided by @heropup - I am just giving a proof of the previously obtained numerical result with a method which can be used for other tower sequences and can also be adapted to find lower limits.

Comment: Nice answer  its seems to build such paper about that problem including you as Author with me , But i will add some analytical results uses dynamical system topic

Comment: Great - I look forward to seeing the paper.

Answer (score 0):

Blockquote
$a_{n}=(1-\dfrac{1}{2})^{(\dfrac{1}{2}-\dfrac{1}{3})^{(\dfrac{1}{3}-\dfrac{1}{4})^{...^{(\dfrac{1}{n}-\dfrac{1}{n+1})}}}}$ 
$a_{n}=(1-\dfrac{1}{2})^{(\dfrac{1}{6})^{(\dfrac{1}{12})^{...^{(\dfrac{1}{n(n+1)})}}}}$
$a_{n}=(\dfrac{1}{2})^{(\dfrac{1}{2(1+2)})^{(\dfrac{1}{2(1+2+3)})^{...^{(\dfrac{1}{2(1+2+3+4+...+n)})}}}}$
Note: every number $M$ has a number between $0$ and $1$ and we have $a \leq b\leq c$ then  $M^{c}\leq M^{b}\leq M^{a}$\

Which
\begin{equation*}
(\dfrac{1}{2})^{(\dfrac{1}{2(1)})^{(\dfrac{1}{2(1)})^{...^{(\dfrac{1}{2(1)})}}}} \leq (\dfrac{1}{2})^{(\dfrac{1}{2(1+2)})^{(\dfrac{1}{2(1+2+3)})^{...^{(\dfrac{1}{2(1+2+3+4+...+n)})}}}}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation}
\label{1}
(\dfrac{1}{2})^{(\dfrac{1}{2})^{(\dfrac{1}{2})^{...^{(\dfrac{1}{2})}}}} \leq (\dfrac{1}{2})^{(\dfrac{1}{2(1+2)})^{(\dfrac{1}{2(1+2+3)})^{...^{(\dfrac{1}{2(1+2+3+4+...+n)})}}}}
\end{equation}
we've got 
$ (1+2) < (1\times2\times3) = 3! < n! $
$ (1+2+3) < (1\times2\times3)= 3! < n! $
$ (1+2+3+4)< (1\times2\times3\times 4) =4! < n! $
$\qquad\qquad\qquad\vdots \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad \vdots\qquad\vdots$
$ (1+2+3+4+\cdots+n)< (1\times2\times3\times\cdots n) =n! = n! $
so
\begin{equation*}
 (\dfrac{1}{2})^{(\dfrac{1}{2(1+2)})^{(\dfrac{1}{2(1+2+3)})^{...^{(\dfrac{1}{2(1+2+3+4+...+n)})}}}}\leq (\dfrac{1}{2})^{(\dfrac{1}{2\times n!})^{(\dfrac{1}{2\times n!})^{...^{(\dfrac{1}{2\times n!})}}}}
\end{equation*}
The larger the denominator, the smaller the number
we have $ n!\leq n!\times n! $
\begin{equation}
\label{2}
(\dfrac{1}{2})^{(\dfrac{1}{2(1+2)})^{(\dfrac{1}{2(1+2+3)})^{...^{(\dfrac{1}{2(1+2+3+4+...+n)})}}}}\leq (\dfrac{1}{2})^{(\dfrac{1}{2\times n!\times n!})^{(\dfrac{1}{2\times n!\times n!})^{...^{(\dfrac{1}{2\times n!\times n!})}}}}
\end{equation}
So from inequality 1 and inequality 2 we find
\begin{equation*}
\label{3}(\dfrac{1}{2})^{(\dfrac{1}{2})^{(\dfrac{1}{2})^{...^{(\dfrac{1}{2})}}}} \leq (\dfrac{1}{2})^{(\dfrac{1}{2(1+2)})^{(\dfrac{1}{2(1+2+3)})^{...^{(\dfrac{1}{2(1+2+3+4+...+n)})}}}}\leq
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation}
\leq
(\dfrac{1}{2})^{(\dfrac{1}{2\times n!\times n!})^{(\dfrac{1}{2\times n!\times n!})^{...^{(\dfrac{1}{2\times n!\times n!})}}}}
\end{equation}
We use the Lim ,we have
\begin{equation*}
\label{4}\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}(\dfrac{1}{2})^{(\dfrac{1}{2})^{(\dfrac{1}{2})^{...^{(\dfrac{1}{2})}}}} \leq \lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}(\dfrac{1}{2})^{(\dfrac{1}{2(1+2)})^{(\dfrac{1}{2(1+2+3)})^{...^{(\dfrac{1}{2(1+2+3+4+...+n)})}}}}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation}\leq \lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}(\dfrac{1}{2})^{(\dfrac{1}{2\times n!\times n!})^{(\dfrac{1}{2\times n!\times n!})^{...^{(\dfrac{1}{2\times n!\times n!})}}}}
\end{equation}
remarque
$
\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\dfrac{1}{2\times n!\times n! }=\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\dfrac{1}{2}\times \dfrac{1}{ n!}\times\dfrac{1}{n!}
=\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\dfrac{1}{2}\times\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{ n!}{n!} }=\dfrac{1}{2} 
$
NOte $ \lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\dfrac{ n!}{n!}=1 $
\begin{equation*}
\label{5}\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}(\dfrac{1}{2})^{(\dfrac{1}{2})^{(\dfrac{1}{2})^{...^{(\dfrac{1}{2})}}}} \leq \lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}(\dfrac{1}{2})^{(\dfrac{1}{2(1+2)})^{(\dfrac{1}{2(1+2+3)})^{...^{(\dfrac{1}{2(1+2+3+4+...+n)})}}}}\leq
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation}
\leq\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} (\dfrac{1}{2})^{(\dfrac{1}{2\times\dfrac{ n!}{ n!} })^{(\dfrac{1}{2\times\dfrac{ n!}{ n!}})^{...^{(\dfrac{1}{2\times\dfrac{ n!}{ n!}})}}}}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation*}
\label{6}(\dfrac{1}{2})^{(\dfrac{1}{2})^{(\dfrac{1}{2})^{...^{(\dfrac{1}{2})}}}} \leq\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}(\dfrac{1}{2})^{(\dfrac{1}{2(1+2)})^{(\dfrac{1}{2(1+2+3)})^{...^{(\dfrac{1}{2(1+2+3+4+...+n)})}}}}\leq 
(\dfrac{1}{2})^{(\dfrac{1}{2})^{(\dfrac{1}{2})^{...^{(\dfrac{1}{2})}}}}
\end{equation*}
so
$\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}a_{n}=(\dfrac{1}{2})^{(\dfrac{1}{2})^{(\frac{1}{2})^{...^{(\dfrac{1}{2})}}}}\simeq 0.6411857445$

Answer (score 0):

$\forall n\in N^{*}:u_{n}=(1-\frac{1}{2})^{(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3})^{(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4})^{...(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1})}}}\gt 0$

$u_{1}=v_{1}=1-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$

$u_{2}=v_{1}^{v_{2}},u_{3}=v_{1}^{v_{2}^{v_{3}}},...,u_{n}=v_{1}^{v_{2}^{v_{3}^{....v_{n}}}},v_{n}=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}=\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$

$\ln u_{n}=v_{2}^{v_{3}^{^{....v_{n}}}}\ln v_{1}=-v_{2}^{v_{3}^{^{....v_{n}}}}\ln 2\lt 0$

$0\lt u_{n}\lt 1$

$\frac{1}{9900}^{\frac{1}{10100}}\approx 0.9991$

$\lim_{n \to \infty }(\frac{1}{(n-1)n})^{\frac{1}{n(n+1)}}=1 $

$n\ge 99\Rightarrow v_{n}^{v_{n+1}}\gt  0.999$

$ A_{n}=v_{99}^{v100^{v_{101}^{...v_{n}}}}\longrightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty }A_{n}\approx 1$

$\lim_{n \to \infty }u_{n}=v_{1}^{v_{2}^{^{...v_{99}}}} $