# What about irrationality of $a_n=(1-\frac12)^{(\frac12-\frac13)^{...^{(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1})}}}$?

Tags: convergence-divergence, irrational-numbers, irrationality-measure

This question is related to my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2822112/156150) which depend on the convergence of this sequence:$a_n=(1-\frac12)^{(\frac12-\frac13)^{...^{(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1})}}}$ however the limit of convergence is not clear even now, But my question here is to ask about irrationality of that sequence ? its clear to me that is rational only for  $ n=1$ ,What about $ n >1$ ?

Comment: don't confuse $a^{b^c}$ with $(a^b)^c$

Answer (score 0):

**Clearly rational only for n=1?**

This is more a check on what is known about these numbers rather than an answer. We have:-

$n=1$  Rational

$n=2$  Irrational, algebraic

$n=3$  Transcendental

$n=4$  ????

So it is clearly irrational for $n=2$ and $3$. However, have you made any progress on the case $n=4$?

Comment: The asserted relation between $a_n$ and $a_{n-1}$ isn't right. For example $a_3=(1/2)^{(1/6)^{1/12}}$, not $((1/2)^{1/6})^{1/12}$, so $a_3^{12}\not=a_2$.

Comment: Agreed - I was misinterpreting the definition.

Comment: If it's still of interest, I have added an answer to the previous question on convergence. The method used can be extended reasonably easily to actually find the limits $l$ and $L$ which are **not** the same for your  sequence.

Comment: How do you know that $a_3$ is transcendental?