# Is $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(A_{n+1}-A_{n})$ finite?

Tags: sequences-and-series, dynamical-systems, ceiling-and-floor-functions, iterated-function-system

The following question is related to my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2822112/156150) about behavior of this sequence $a_{n}=(1-\frac12)^{ \left( \frac12-\frac13 \right)^{...^{ \left( \frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1} \right)}}}$.  Now I define a new sequence generated from the linked sequence by:

$A_{n}= \lfloor (2n!((1-\frac12)^{(\frac12-\frac13)^{...^{(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1})}}}) \rfloor$ where $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ is the floor function.  My question here is:  Is $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(A_{n+1}-A_{n})$ finite?

I have calculated some terms for $(A_{n+1}-A_{n})$ and it seems the difference does not grow fast enough to lead to divergence,  which leads me to guess that the overall limit is finite.

---

The terms can be written much more simply:

$$A_n = \Bigl\lfloor 2n! \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^{ {{\left( \frac{1}{6} \right)}^{\cdots} }^{ \left( \frac{n}{n+1} \right)}} \Bigr\rfloor$$

and with a little effort you can replace $\left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^x$ to $2^{-x}$, better revealing the structure of the term:

$$\Bigl\lfloor 2n!\ 2^{{{\left(-6 \right)}^\cdots}^{\pm \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)}} \Bigr\rfloor$$

Comment: Why do you leave the terms as $(1 - \frac{1}{2})$ rather than simplify all such terms and thus better see the structure of the series?

Comment: I didn't get any simplification than that

Comment: Oh, thanks for that , I wrote it by difference in the exponent just to let people that is present telescopic in the exponent

Comment: I think there is a typo. It should've been $$A_n=\left\lfloor (2n)!\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{\cdots \left(\color{red}{\frac{1}{n(n+1)}}\right)}}\right\rfloor$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the alternating nature of your original sequence, it is easy to prove (from what has already been said in you previous post) that $\frac{1}{2}\leq a_n<1$ for all $n$. Therefore, $$A_{n+1}-A_n=$$ $$\lfloor (2n+2)!\cdot a_{n+1}\rfloor-\lfloor (2n)!\cdot a_n\rfloor>$$ $$(2n+2)!\cdot a_{n+1}-(2n)!\cdot a_n-1>$$ $$\frac{(2n+2)!}{2}-(2n)!-1=$$ $$(2n)!\left(2n^2+3n\right)-1.$$
This last value clearly diverges, as does the original.