# The limit of the sequence: $U_n=(2\times3)^{-(3\times4)^{..^{\mathrm{-n(n+1)}}}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, exact-sequence

I trying solving this equation [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2822112/convergence-of-a-n-1-frac12-frac12-frac13-frac1n-frac1n/) ,I find that the limit l verify:
$2=l^{-6^{-12^{..^{\mathrm{-\infty}}}}}$ So now I need the limit of  $U_n=(2\times3)^{-(3\times4)^{..^{\mathrm{-n(n+1)}}}}$

Comment: Avoid the use of $*$ to denote multiplication, that's used in programming, not in Mathematics. Use `\cdot` or `\times`

Comment: ok thanks for remark

Comment: Could you elaborate how the expression you wrote is related to the problem you linked to? Moreover, the limit of a sequence cannot contain $n$ in it; it must be a number, so your expression $2=\ell^{-6^{-12^{\ldots^{-n(n+1)}}}}$ does not make sense to me.

Answer (score -1):

$a_n=(1-1/2)^{(1/2-1/3)^{..\mathrm{(1/n-1/(1+n))}}}=(1/2)^{(1/6)^{..\mathrm{1/(n(n+1))}}}=2^{-{6^{-{..^{-{n(n+1)^{\mathrm{-1}}}}}}}}$ suppose this consequence converge to $l$
so it is easy to see that the limit $l$ verify :
$2=l^{-{6^{-{..^{-{n(n+1)^{\mathrm{}}}}}}}}$
when n->infinity
so $2=l^{-{6^{-{..^{-{\infty^{\mathrm{}}}}}}}}$
because:
$a^{b^{\mathrm{-1}}}=l$ require that $a=l^{b}$
@Snaw

Comment: but now what is the value of $6^{-{..^-{\mathrm{\infty}}}}$

Comment: By the way it's better to answer as a comment next time because this way I did not get notified of the reply (and also in order to not attract downvotes). Your mistake is when you write $2=\ell^{\ldots^{-n(n+1)}}$, since $n$ is the variable that goes to infinity then once you have taken the limit (introduced the symbol $\ell$) you can no longer have $n$ around. It is not better that you write this as $2=\ell^{\ldots^{-\infty}}$ because this likewise has no mathematical meaning (you cannot have the symbol $\infty$ inside an expression).

Answer (score -1):

I have consider the sequence $U_n=((n-1)n)^{-(n(n+1))}$ this sequence go to $0$
So now : 2=$l^{-U_0^{-..\mathrm{0}}}$ where $U_0=6^{-12}$  and $U_1= 20^{-30}$... until $U_n$

Comment: You have already posted an answer. You can edit that post to add new information instead of making another answer.

Comment: OK until tomorrow